# Remove "Server: Apache" from response headers

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http-headers

I want to know how to remove the Server header completely that apache sends in the response.

Initially, it was showing full server info  like `Server: Apache (Ubuntu 14.04)` in the response headers.
But I read somewhere to add this in apache2.conf

```
ServerTokens ProductOnly

ServerSignature Off
```

It didn't remove the header but only changed it to `Server: Apache`

I even tried from PHP to remove that header with `header_remove('Server');`. But still no luck.

So, I want to remove that completely.

Thanks,

PS: if it's possible to change the value to a fake value for eg: `Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0` then it is fine too.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to modify the Apache source code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979502/12154890 to change the header without mod_security

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server ID/token header is controlled by "ServerTokens" directive (provided by mod_core). Aside from modifying the Apache HTTPD source code, or using mod_security module, there is no other way to fully suppress the server ID header.

With the mod_security approach, you can disable all of the module's directives/functions in the modsecurity.conf file, and leverage only the server header ID directive without any additional "baggage."
(c) Chipster

Answer (score 6):

To build on the answer by @Maxym on using the `mod_security` module - NOTE that you CANNOT remove the server header ENTIRELY ( that is only possible through source code editing/recompilation ) with this module, however you can rename the public server signature - say "NinjaServer" via this
`mod_security` module !

To do that;

We have to ( in httpd.conf or equivalent ) keep/set;

```
ServerTokens Full
```

Then via mod_security2.conf;

```
SecServerSignature "NinjaServer"
```

Also, its better for the mod_security module to be loaded last to avoid notices in the apache error log.

For a OpenSuse 15.x / Apache 2.4.x Setup, the actual steps are;

```
 zypper -v in apache2-mod_security2 // install mod_security
 a2enmod security2                  // enable the module
 a2enmod unique_id                  // this was needed too...
 a2enmod -l                         // verify loaded
```

Next, edit httpd.conf.local (under /etc/apache2) and set;

```
 ServerTokens Full
```

Next, edit mod_security2.conf (under /etc/apache2) and set;

```
 SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly         // only remove apache server name
 SecServerSignature "NinjaServer"    // some name other than Apache
```

Also comment out ( this example is just for modifying Public Server Signature );

```
# Include /usr/share/apache2-mod_security2/rules/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf
```

Then restart apache via

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

And if you were to check your headers ( Browser's Dev Tools ) now, you will see the
Server name appearing as NinjaServer :-)

Answer (score 6):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296886/completely-hide-server-name-apache#26300136) is the best way I found:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2
```

Then add this to `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` (you can use any name, here I've used space):

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleEngine on
    ServerTokens Min
    SecServerSignature " "
</IfModule>
```

and restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now when you run something like:

```
curl -v http://localhost:80/ | head
```

you should get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 25 Jan 2021 09:31:11 GMT
* Server  is not blacklisted
< Server:
```

For full details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883445/1741690).

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Raspberry Pi OS: Raspbian Buster (Release date: March 4th 2021
Kernel version: 5.10)

Apache Version: 2.4.38

Installation of mod-security

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2 -y
```

modify the security.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf
```

as follows

```
ServerTokens Prod
```

copy template

```
sudo cp /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf-recommended /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
```

modify modsecurity.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
```

as follows

```
SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
SecServerSignature "Noop"
```

Restart server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Source

- https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/server/apache/install-modsecurity-apache-module/