# Completely hide server name Apache Windows

Tags: windows, apache, apache-config

Hope you guys are doing well.

I have one query so I have added the below lines in my windows Apache **httpd.conf** file with the below tags:-

**ServerSignature Off**,

**ServerTokens Prod**,

**HostnameLookups Off**,

**TraceEnable off**

And I am getting the below O/P like **Server: Apache** by using curl -I

Actually I am looking for the O/P like **Server: Unknown** or **Server:""**

Note :- Here my windows Apache version is **Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64)**

Kindly help me here how I can hide this Server information as well, as its a security threat to our Instances.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean 'output' by 'O/P'?

Answer (score 0):

Apache say:

> Also note that disabling the Server: header does nothing at all to make your server more secure. The idea of "security through obscurity" is a myth and leads to a false sense of safety.

You would need to modify the source code, or install mod_security, and then you can add:

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecServerSignature Unknown
```

You can modify the source code as follows: [How to change Apache's 'Server:' header without mod_security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979501/how-to-change-apaches-server-header-without-mod-security)

To remove server header by editing source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66667833/12154890
Editing the source is probably the only way to remove the Server: header completely.

Since you are using windows, if you cannot install additional modules like mod_security or recompile, you cannot remove it.