# How to completely hide header information in Apache

Tags: apache, webserver

I am trying to hide the Apache Web Server Information for security reasons, Previously we were getting following output on running curl command,

< Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n

But i made the changes to my conf file and added below following lines,

ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod

After adding above lines in the conf file I am not getting following web server header output while running the curl command.

< Server: Apache

To get rid of the "Apache" information I followed the below link and updated ap_release.h file under Include folder of apache install directory as mentioned in the below Stack Overflow Link.

[How to change Apache's 'Server:' header without mod_security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979501/how-to-change-apaches-server-header-without-mod-security?newreg=f2ce733fbef0402b91549b713df648a3)

Can someone guide me how to compile the source code, Also do we have to compile all the available source code or just the source code where I have made the modification.

Regards,
D

Comment: Shouldn't you decide for one of  "Off", "ServerTokens", "Prod"?